# Changing positions of div panels

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have 3 panels: 1 - 2 - 3

The effect i want to have is that the three panels are moving forward.

- First i hide the panel number one (fadeOut)
- Second, I change the id of panel number 2 to 1 , panel number 3 to 2, then I change the panel number 1(hidden) to 3.
- Finally, i set fade in for panel number 3 (old id is number 1)

I dont know where i did wrong because when i tried running, the effect is that panel 1 fade out then it fade in again , at the same position. 

P/S: is there any plug-in in jquery can do this?

 Thank you

Comment: Please show your HTML markup and the javascript you're currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try a method that doesn't involve changing the div IDs. It's good practice to keep the ID unique to that div. Instead of changing the IDs, you could use a class for all 3 of them, and get jQuery to fade out the first instance of that class, then use the `insertAfter()` function to insert this element after the last instance of that class.

```
var elements = $('.myclass');
elements.first().insertAfter(elements.last());
```